# J2ME LWUIT - Drawing email address error

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I'm working on my J2ME application trying to fix some bugs. One of this happens when I want to show a email address.

I have a string with a valid email address (mark@mail.com as example) and when I use `drawString` of LWUIT it draws the email address without the `@` (markmail.com)

I try to draw the chain `"@@@@"` and shows `""`

Any idea?. Is it necessary to add some special character to draw `@`'s?

Comment: have you tried something like `"\u0040"`? if I understand correctly this would be the value for commercial at (`@`) in [UTF-8 character table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was the charset of the resource file.

I added the @ to the charset and now it works

Thanks anyway

Comment: [accept your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to help the future readers of this post